# How do i design this screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i create this `Layout` in `android studio`? I try to write some codes but i can' t complete that. Thank you for helps. Should i use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or `TableLayout` for same viewing for **all devices**.

[image: layout]
[image: layout]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNgWM.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#404040">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:text="12345678901"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#a0a0a0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.45" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="tv1"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_weight="0.36"
            android:textColor="#55ff1c"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla bla bla bla bla"
        android:id="@+id/cbx1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use relative layout, it would be better.

Comment: how can i use that? i am newbie on android.

Comment: You can search for it, how to use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: user relative layout as parent and then drag and drop your controls as per your need

Comment: i try to use relativelayout but if i used RL, it would change controls location depends on edittext width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change margin/padding/fontsize/color as required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#404040"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tv1"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:elegantTextHeight="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="11"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="12345678901"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#a0a0a0"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="tv1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#55ff1c" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbx1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="bla bla bla bla bla"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.8"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton1"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton2"/>
            </RadioGroup>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Text View" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Text View" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottomtextview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I made a design as you need. But you may need to set height and width by your own. take a look to the below code.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Edit Text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Text View" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check Box" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Radio Button" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Radio Button" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Text View"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Text View" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text View"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I designed this by linear layout. hope it helps you.